# How can we generate individual billings for customers according to there usage in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, billing

I have a single AWS account. I have mutliple customers who are using the AWS services like ec2 instances,elb,auto scaling etc.

How can I generate individual billings as per the usage for a single customer?

Note : I cant create multiple sub accounts in AWS.

Any other suggestion ??

Answer (score 0):

You can assign and use cost allocation tags to all of you aws resources. One tag for each billing entity should probably do what you want.

> You can use cost allocation tags to categorize and track your AWS
>   costs. When you apply tags to your AWS resources (such as Amazon EC2
>   instances or Amazon S3 buckets), AWS generates a cost allocation
>   report as a comma-separated value (CSV file) with your usage and costs
>   aggregated by your tags. You can apply tags that represent business
>   categories (such as cost centers, application names, or owners) to
>   organize your costs across multiple services.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/cost-alloc-tags.html

Comment: it means if one customer is having m3.medium with ebs and rds can I calculate its cost ?